# how to connect to a password protected cassandra using pig

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I have a cassandra cluster with username and password set in the password.properties file, I could'n figure out how to use pig's CassandraStorage to load and write data to this cluster. Without the password, the function is fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In CassandraStorage#initSchema you would want to add a call to build an AuthenticationRequest struct and add a call to client#login just before client#set_keyspace.

Created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3042